# Unexpected token < while using ajax and codeigniter

Tags: ajax

I have wasted my day finding solution for this.
This is my jquery function
And this is the error I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"
Please Help
Thanks

```js
$('#post_comment').click(function(){
  var question_id=$('#question_id').val();
  var comment=$('#comment').val();
  var user_id=$('#user_id').val();

  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'questions/update_question',
    data : {question_id:question_id,comment:comment,user_id:user_id},

    success:function(response) {
      $('#comment_textarea').toggleClass("hidden");
      // alert(response);
      var result=JSON.parse(response);
      var div1="<div class='row comment_rows>";
      var div2="<div class='col-sm-9 comment_description_column'></div>";
      var div3="<div class='col-sm-3 comment_description_userinfo'></div></div>";

      $('.comment_rows:last').append(div1,div2,div3);
      $('.comment_description_column:last').text(result.comment_description);
      $('.comment_description_userinfo:last').text(result.user_id);   

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log("Status: " + xhr.status);
      console.log("Message: " + thrownError);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your ajax you forgot to close a class with ==> '

```
$('#post_comment').click(function(){
  var question_id=$('#question_id').val();
  var comment=$('#comment').val();
  var user_id=$('#user_id').val();

  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'questions/update_question',
    data : {question_id:question_id,comment:comment,user_id:user_id},

    success:function(response) {
      $('#comment_textarea').toggleClass("hidden");
      // alert(response);
      var result=JSON.parse(response);
      var div1="<div class='row comment_rows>";
      // you forget to close the class -----^  

      var div2="<div class='col-sm-9 comment_description_column'></div>";
      var div3="<div class='col-sm-3 comment_description_userinfo'></div></div>";

      $('.comment_rows:last').append(div1,div2,div3);
      $('.comment_description_column:last').text(result.comment_description);
      $('.comment_description_userinfo:last').text(result.user_id);         

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log("Status: " + xhr.status);
      console.log("Message: " + thrownError);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I would like to but I am not that reputed yet to upvote.